# Looking for a Good Resource for SQL Exercises

Tags: sql

Are there any good resources on the web for practicing SQL? I have been studying the language for nearly a year now, and I am looking for additional exercises to improve my abilities to write SQL queries. I have previously worked with the exercises on sql-ex.ru and codefights.com.

Comment: What's wrong with trying to solve the problems on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the tutorial [provided by mode analytics](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-in-mode/). [W3 schools is pretty good too.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

For more advanced stuff, check out the [window functions](http://www.windowfunctions.com/questions/intro/) site.